# Is it possible to place all Variables and Methods inside of a Class?

Tags: ruby, class

Sorry for the beginner question. I followed a quick tutorial to make a Ruby Quiz, which I'll explain.

I created a class as below:

```
class Question
    attr_accessor :prompt, :answer

    def initialize(prompt, answer)
        @prompt = prompt
        @answer = answer
    end
end
```

I then created a variable as the question:

```
p1 = "What color is an apple?\n(a)red\n(b)orange\n(c)yellow"
```

Then an array to store the question and assign an answer:

```
questions = Question.new(p1, "a")
```

Below that a method:

```
def run_test(questions)
    answer = ""
    score = 0
    for question in questions
        puts question.prompt
        answer = gets.chomp()
        if answer == question.answer
            score += 1
        end
    end
    puts ("You got " + score.to_s + "/" + questions.length().to_s)
end
```

Now, I want to modularize a bit so the Question class contains the variable/question, array/answer and method so that I can refer to it from another file (like a main app file). Is it possible to place all these elements into the class so that I can refer to it from another file (main app)?

Is there a better way of doing this? I tried not having everything in the class but different elements were not accessible from another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Ruby community!

> Is there a better way of doing this?

When it comes to programming there is always other ways of doing things, sometimes considered better, sometimes worse, it depends on case by case basis. It's good to learn what is considered best practices and practice them until it becomes your default way of coding. As many things in life take best practices as guidelines as opposed to rules.

In your case everything was fine until you wanted to import the code to reuse it in another project, so the abstraction you chose is not working anymore, this happens and it's fine, it's time to refactor it!

Looking at your code at this moment, the question class is just a glorified data structure, you could achieve something similar with a hash `{ prompt: '', answer: ''}` meaning your class has the data portion but no logic portion, my first suggestion is to move the answer checking logic to a method in the Question class.

```rb
class Question
  attr_reader :prompt, :correct_answer

  def initialize(prompt, correct_answer)
    @prompt = prompt
    @correct_answer = correct_answer
  end

  def score(answer)
    return 1 if answer == @correct_answer
    return 0
  end
end
```

The benefit of this approach is that eventually you may decide to do things like "this question is worth 2 points", "when the user inputs `(several spaces)c(several spaces)` I want to treat as just `c`" and this would be the place to implement that logic.

The next thing you can consider doing is introducing a new class, the one that represents a Test/Quiz/Exam. That class is responsible for doing the logic that you implemented in `run_test`. With that you should be able to import and reuse your code. When writing down this class, think about the possible things you can do with a test, can you "start it", "end it", "answer question", "go to next question" and so on.

It's very common in programming to avoid coupling IO and your code, IO in this case it's the `puts question.prompt` and the `answer = gets.chomp()`.

One could expect the following API to work but it really depends on your preference and what you are trying to achieve:

```rb
def run_test(quiz)
  quiz.questions.each do |question|
    puts question.prompt
    answer = gets.chomp()
    quiz.answer(question, answer)
  end
  puts ("You got #{quiz.score} / #{quiz.maximum_score}")
end
```

You see with this approach the main focus of the code is looping through questions and proving IO, if you were building a web page you could still use the Quiz and Question class, what would change is how you prompt the question and how you obtain the answer. What you hid from the consumers of your class is how you score the test, what's the maximum score, what's the person current score?

Other things in my mind when I drafted this code:
- should I have a `start` method that resets the score to 0?
- should I hide questions behind a `next_question` method, this way I can return `nil` if no more questions are left, with the current approach one could answer the quiz multiple times by running `run_test` multiple times and getting all the added score "You got 23 / 10".

I hope this gives you ideas of what you could do next.